# Is object fix-sized in java

Tags: java, object, memory, jvm, instance

In the Java programming environment, where each data type has a predetermined size, can it be inferred that objects also possess a fixed size post-initialization?

I've consulted ChatGPT and read numerous articles on the topic, but there seems to be a discrepancy in understanding. While some sources claim that object sizes are not fixed, I remain unconvinced. Could you clarify where my understanding might be lacking?

Comment: What do you count as the size of an object? Do you include the size of other elements pointed to by this object?

Comment: the elements pointed to also has fixed size for me, as i (me as object) only stored their references (which is fiexed size in a given environment) not themselve.

Comment: What do you mean by an object size? How much memory an object takes in Java heap? Or how much memory it takes on-heap + off-heap? Including JVM-specific object headers or not? Counting scalar-replaced objects or not?

Comment: A short answer is - implementation-defined.

Comment: IIt would be reasonable to conclude that an object once constructed doesn’t change its own size, but iisn't specified.

Comment: what is the size of for example an `ArrayList`? Does it include the size of the array, including the memory needed to store its elements?

Comment: @user85421 ArrayList instance size as i understand = headers size + sums of primitive attributes + memory address size * number of reference attributes

Comment: so, does it include "the memory needed to store its elements" or not? If *yes*, then the answer to your question - "Is object fix-sized" - is no (since the size of the `ArrayList` will change if more elements are added than its actual capacity, that is, the `array` needed to store the elements must be changed)

Comment: what do you mean by its elements?

Comment: elements? when I do `list.add(123)` - `123` is a (new) element in the list ( [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) of `add()`: "Appends the specified element to the end of this list.")

Comment: when you initialize a list (say `list1`) for the first time the jvm give it a fixed size, and when its full it create another list (another object) with (for example) x2 size of the first, then copy old elements to it and make list1 refere to this newly created object. So what was change is not the size of object but the reference

Comment: `lis1` will still be the same reference, even if its capacity is increased - the array used to store the elements will be changed, and that is why I asked "Does it include the size of the array"

Comment: @user85421 thank you, you are right, i misunderstand. In that case also the object that list1 refer to still have the same size, right? because all refs(memory adress) have the same size?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In java, we have primitives and references.

What are primitives? It's a hard coded list: `double`, `float`, `long`, `int`, `short`, `byte`, `char`, and `boolean`. That is it. They are baked into the language, there are no class files representing these types. They have always been part of java, will always be, and you can't make more.

They are all fixed size. (double and long are 64-bit, float and int are 32-bit. short/char are 16, byte/bool are 8, but the last 4 are the inferior primitives and many operations, such as 'numeric addition' cannot operate on these last 4; if you attempt to, say, add 2 `short` values together what actually happens is that both short values are converted to int values, those are added up, and then the result is converted back to a short if your java code requires it to be one - and hence, usually, you need a explicit cast in your java code to make that happen).

So, what are references? **Everything else**.

```
String x = "foo";
```

Here, x is **a reference**. It's not `"foo"`. No, what happens there is that somewhere on the heap (imagine a giant beach), an object is instantiated and it contains `"foo"` somehow. How? That's an implementation detail; it requires checking the source of `java.lang.String` and it may change in future versions. (Imagine a treasure chest, buried in the giant beach).

`x` is not the treasure chest. It's the map that leads to it. Maps are simple, fit on fixed size bits of paper, are easy to copy around. Same thing with references: They are fixed size (what size? Depends on the JVM and various settings; generally 64-bit, could be 32-bit), and just point at an object, they aren't, themselves, an object.

Objects have non-static fields and each field requires some space, hence, trivially, **objects are not fixed size**. They are as large as the fields its class definition contains dictates they must be:

```
class Example {
  int a;
  boolean b;
  String z;
}

... elsewhere ...

Example example = new Example();
```

This creates a new Example object. The JVM does this by finding some room on the heap (some room on the beach where no one has been burying treasure chests yet) for 1 instance of Example. This requires *at least* 13 bytes (9, on a JVM that uses 32-bit refs, such as a 32-bit JVM or one with CompressedOOPS on), though it may take a little more because modern CPUs do not like operating on things that aren't on word boundaries, on 64-bit is the word boundary on modern CPUs - so it's probably 16 bytes no matter what you do here.

Tha's because it takes 4 bytes to store that `int`, 1 to store that bool, and 4 (or 8) to store that reference to a String. It doesn't have to, itself, store the string content - just 'the treasure map' that leads to it (yes, an instance of `Example` is a treasure chest, which contains 1 piece of paper with a number written on it, one with 'true'/'false' written on it, and.. another treasure map that leads to another treasure that contains the value of that string. It can be blank (`null`)).

Usually it takes a little more: Objects know what they are, which also takes some storage, but that part, at least, is 'fixed' (all objects have a header). How large? JVM detail; a JVM is free to implement this however it wants, neither the Java Lang Spec nor the Java VM Spec dictates any particular rule here. Just that an object must know what it is (`obj.getClass()` must 'work').

Then, the `example` variable itself takes 4 to 8 bytes, as it is a reference.

So, we have:

- An instance of Example, somewhere on the heap. It most likely occupies 32 bytes (16 bytes for the header, 16 to contain the data in its fields). Add 2 long fields to it, and it'd take 16 bytes more. It takes as many bytes as is needed to cover its header and the fields it has, and you can have up to 256 fields in a class. Every *field* takes a known, fixed amount of bytes to represent, though (because everything is a primitive or a reference, and thus, fixed size). The JVM knows beforehand how big Examples are, so within one running JVM, all `Example` instances are fixed size - but note that they may contain refs to other objects, and the creation of 1 Example instance can in turn create more objects.

Consider:

```
public class Example {
  private Example next;

  public Example(int amount) {
    if (amount < 1) return;
    next = new Example(amount - 1);
  }
}
```

If you then call `new Example(random.nextInt(100))`, then that one line will cause a random amount of memory to be consumed - each individual Example instance is fixed size (probably 24 bytes - 16 for a header, 8 for the one field it has), but a single `new Example(100)` call makes 100 Example objects.

When we say 'java is pass by value', what's passed is the primitive or the treasure map. **Never** the treasure:

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
int y = 100;

foo(x, y);
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(y);

void foo(List<String> x, int y) {
  x.add("Hello!");
  y = 200;
}
```

This prints 'Hello!', and then '100' - the `x` appears 'modified' but the y appears not. Huh? It makes sense once you realize what references imply. What you pass to `foo` is **a copy of your treasure map**, along with **a copy of your piece of paper that has '100' on it**. That method then follows its copy of your treasure map (`.` is java for 'follow the map and dig'), opens the treasure chest it finds, puts something inside, closes it, and buries it again in the same place. Then it takes the copy of that paper with '100' on it, wipes out, and writes 200 on it, then ends - and as all methods do, as they end, they burn all the pieces of paper they have. So, that was useless then. It also burns its copy of the map.

But if you then check your paper with the value on it, it is, of course, still 100, but if you take your treasure map, follow it, dig, and look - there's now a thing inside.

Comment: An individual object, once constructed, takes an amount of memory that does not change for the lifetime of that object.  It may hold references to objects of varying size, or to a graph of references of varying size, but the object itself never changes how much memory it consumes.

Comment: I'm not sure where this answer claims otherwise.

Comment: References are not ‘everything else’. In Java we also have objects. Amid all this nonsensical waffle about references and random numbers and pieces of paper and treasure chests I can’t see where you’ve answered the actual question.

Comment: I think the OP meant to ask "Once created, does an object ever change its size", and that you've interpreted their question as "Are all objects the same size." But I think the question is too unclear to answer.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thank you very much. I think that is my answer: `The JVM knows beforehand how big Examples are, so within one running JVM, all Example instances are fixed size`

Comment: @Htam This is not always true, and the answer you've accepted is inaccurate. For example, different instances of `java.lang.Class` have different size - you may verify this with [JOL tool](https://github.com/openjdk/jol). This is because in addition to object fields visible in Java sources, JVM implementation may append hidden fields, inaccessible on application level, and the number of these fields may vary between instances.

Comment: @apangin thank for your helping. I mean a given instance has a fixed size, not all instances of a given class have an equal fixed size. Is that true?

Comment: @Htam What apangin is talking about, is a JVM implementation detail. The root issue here is that the JVM spec effectively says: "A JVM will run your java code such that it works as you expect, and the systemic load it'll take to do its job, as well as the strategies it employs, are either entirely unspecified, or at best loosely bounded, so, there is _no way_ to truly answer your question. Some JVMs elect to append some extra bookkeeping data to objects for various purposes. No part of the JVMS/JLS requires that it do this. Some JVMs do _that_ with variable sizes.

Comment: @rzwitserloot can you give me a case example in which the size of a given object change at run-time (maybe some extra data was appended to it after its creation with header and its attributes...)? i think about that but i dont get anything :)

Comment: @Htam you're asking the wrong person - apangin came up with the 'weeeellll on some JVMs they do some extra bookkeeping, not mentioned or required in any way in the JLS/JVMS' part.

Answer (score 3):

> can it be inferred that objects also possess a fixed size post-initialization?

No. Java Virtual Machine Specification does not require an object to have fixed size. A valid JVM may or may not resize objects - this depends on the particular implementation.

##### How can the size of an object change?

To begin with, what is an object size? If we define an object size as the amount of storage consumed by the specified object, it can definitely change at runtime.

Each Java object is associated with a monitor, which can be locked with a `synchronized` statement or a `synchronized` method. Since the majority of objects are not used for synchronization, there is no sense in pre-allocating a monitor for each object. Popular JVM implementations, in particular, HotSpot JVM, inflate object monitors only when needed. This means, the amount of storage consumed by an object may increase in the case of a lock contention on this object.

##### But can the *heap* memory consumed by an object change?

Yes. Well, again, this is implementation defined, but there are examples when an object size in the heap changes.

Each Java object can have an [identity hash code](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)). This hash code is usually stored in an object header. But as with monitors, identity hash code is typically computed only for a few Java objects, so it's wasteful to reserve memory for the hash code for every object.

[Project Lilliput](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/lilliput/Main) shrinks object headers by throwing out rarely used header bits. However, computing `identityHashCode` may result in appending an invisible field to the object to store its hash code, thus increasing the object size in the heap. See [Compact Identity Hashcode](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/lilliput/Compact+Identity+Hashcode) for details.

Comment: Thank you ver much.
I mean by object size only its composent size; headers size + attributes sizes, attributes can be primitive or references to objects (which also is the size of a memory address)

Comment: @Htam Right, and that's what I showed in my answer that the headers size of an object may change at runtime.

Comment: can you open this please :) how the header size change at run-time? (for example will JVM insert header to object when instantiated and then delete it & let its space free for using before object's lifcycle finish?)

Comment: @Htam I linked [the article](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/lilliput/Compact+Identity+Hashcode) named Compact Identity Hashcode that describes how an object header may grow after GC for identity-hashed objects.